# How to update and add a block of text a conf.d file using Powershell?

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I have a config file named "conf.d" that I need to update with powershell automation.  Here is what 1 block of the conf.d file looks like:

```
- name: NameHere

    url: www.example.com

    http_response_status_code: (1|2|3)\d\d

    collect_response_time: true

    disable_ssl_validation: false

    ignore_ssl_warning: true

    check_certificate_expiration: true

    days_warning: 30

    days_critical: 10

    tags:
        - Name:Tag
```

The rest of the file is just that block of configuration repeated over and over on top of each other.  Is there a Powershell script that I can write that will add another one of these blocks to the end of the file?

Ideally I would do this with variables as well in the name, url, and tags slots.

Comment: You are after the `Add-Content` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. In order to do so you might want to prepare a block as a template and include variables that can be replaced by their values. As mentioned in the comments you can use [`Add-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/add-content?view=powershell-6) to append on the file or you could use [`Out-File`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Out-File?view=powershell-6) with `-append`.

```
$name = "test"
$content = "Name:$name"
$content | Out-File test.txt
```

Comment: Thank you. Looks like I might need some encoding as well, probably UTF-8